# How do I approximate number of calculations/operations/memory/hardware is required for a 2^18 point FFT on chip?

Tags: fpga, signal-processing, dsp, vlsi, fft

I am looking for FFT implementation on Chip/FPGA. I need a high-resolution FFT which is a minimum of 2^18 points. However, I need to approximate how much hardware will I require for this process. 
I am aware of advancements in this field of research and I was able to see a lot of people were able to implement their 1024, 2048, etc. point FFTs efficiently by using fewer operations/memory/area/power consumption. My concern is on a high level. I just need to approximate how much hardware will I require for this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an \$N\$-point FFT will require \$\log_2N\$ stages, and each stage will have roughly \$N\$ multiplications and additions (although many of those will turn out to be trivial once you see what the twiddle factors are).

If you want to pipeline the computation then add \$N\$ flip-flops for every pipeline stage.

The actual complexity in gates or LUTS for a multiply/adder will depend a great deal on the nature of your input data type and your accuracy requirements. On the other hand, limits on the silicon resources and power will limit how much computation you can really do.

Comment: Will there be (log2N)*N multipliers and (log2N)*N adders or is it an estimate for both combined.

Comment: The number of adders and the number of multipliers are both O(Nlog2N).